# How to write kubernetes deployment to get the latest image built using GCP cloudbuild

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-build

I am trying to do the CI/CD with GCP cloudbuild.

1. I have a k8s cluster ready in GCP. check the deployment manifest bellow.
2. I have a cloudbuild.yaml ready to build new image and push it to registry and command to change the deployment image. check the cloudbuild yaml bellow.

Previously, I used to push the image using the **TAG latest** for the docker image and use the same tag in deployment but it didn't pull the latest image so  Now I have changed it to use the **TAG $COMMIT_SHA**. Now, I am not able to figure out the way to pass the new image with TAG based on commit_sha to the deployment.

***nginx-deployment.yaml***

```
apiVersion: extensions/v1beta1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: mynginx
spec:
  replicas: 3
  minReadySeconds: 50
  strategy:
    type: RollingUpdate
    rollingUpdate:
      maxUnavailable: 1
      maxSurge: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx

  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
        - image: gcr.io/foods-io/cloudbuildtest-image:latest
          name: nginx
          ports:
            - containerPort: 80
```

***cloudbuild.yaml***

```
steps:
  #step1      
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: [ 'build', '-t', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuildtest-image:$COMMIT_SHA', '.' ]
  #step 2
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/docker'
  args: ['push', 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuildtest-image:$COMMIT_SHA']
  #STEP-3
- name: 'gcr.io/cloud-builders/kubectl'
  args: ['set', 'image', 'deployment/mynginx', 'nginx=gcr.io/foods-io/cloudbuildtest-image:$COMMIT_SHA']
  env:
  - 'CLOUDSDK_COMPUTE_ZONE=us-central1-a'
  - 'CLOUDSDK_CONTAINER_CLUSTER=cloudbuild-test'
images:
- 'gcr.io/$PROJECT_ID/cloudbuildtest-image'
```

> Note: I repeat previously I was using the latest tag to the image and
>   as is the same in deployment I expected to pull the new image with my
>   3rd steps in cloudbuild but that didn't so I made the above changes in
>   TAG but now wondering how do I make changes to deployment manifest. Is
>   using the **helm** only solution here?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need a step to replace the tag in your deployment.yaml, one way to do it is to use an environment variable and use `envsubst` to replace it.

Change deployment.yaml:

```
    - image: gcr.io/foods-io/cloudbuildtest-image:$COMMIT_SHA
```

Use some `bash` script to replace the variable (using the `ubuntu` [step](https://cloud.google.com/cloud-build/docs/create-custom-build-steps) for example):

```sh
envsubst '$COMMIT_SHA' < deployment.yaml > nginx-deployment.yaml
```

Alternative using `sed`:

```sh
sed -e 's/$COMMIT_SHA/'"$COMMIT_SHA"'/g' deployment.yaml > /workspace/nginx-deployment.yaml
```

Comment: Thanks I got the concept now, will change the nginx-deployment.yaml with $COMMIT_SHA but how am I going to get the deployment.yaml a bit confused.

Comment: you can share files between steps in the `/workspace` mount. so you could simply send the output of `envsubst` to `/workspace/deployment.yaml` and apply it from there in another step. see https://medium.com/google-cloud/how-to-pass-data-between-cloud-build-steps-de5c9ebc4cdd

Comment: I am getting this issue in logs when using te envsubst ```docker: Error response from daemon: OCI runtime create failed: container_linux.go:345: starting container process caused "exec: \"envsubst\": executable file not found in $PATH": unknown.
time="2019-10-16T12:28:08Z" level=error msg="error waiting for container: context canceled"```

Comment: ok, that means that `gettext-base` is not installed on that system. you should be able to fix this with `apt-get install -y gettext-base` before using `envsubst`. if that doesnt work, there are a few other options to replace the variable with `awk` or `sed`.

Comment: I am trying to use ```sed``` but not able to comeup with exact command to replace the line with image with new image yet.

Comment: Yes, thanks I made few more changes to the sed because it was troubling when adding the variable on both end was substituting the value instead and the sed was not working fine now its OK, made edit to your answer thanks.